# SpringBoot SOAP without XSD file

Tags: spring-boot, soap

First time to code a SOAP (and as a *producer*) in the same SpringBoot REST codebase.
With a simple Google search am able to do a quick refresher about SOAP:

- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-soap-web-service
- https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/
- https://dzone.com/articles/creating-a-soap-web-service-with-spring-boot-start

That said, all tutorials requires to create an "XSD" file.
**"Is there a way to create a producer SOAP without supplying the XSD file with SpringBoot?"**
is the main question. As I haven't seen any tutorial not following the contract-first approach.

Also, have sub-questions that doesn't sound well for me:

- Namespace, should this be PROD url or could be dynamic URL?
- PortTypeName, any info what's this for?
- LocationUri, is it similar to REST controller as the class request mapping url?
- Schema, can this be done via Java beans only without any XSD/XML file through SpringBoot?

Apologies to ask many noob questions, but highly appreciate any informative answers.

Comment: The first link explicitly states:
Spring-WS only supports the contract-first development style.